# Is Lipschitz "type" function Continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function satisfying $f(x)-f(y) \leq k \vert x-y \vert$ for some $k \in \mathbb R$ and $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R$. Is $f$ continuous and differentiable?

By taking $f(x)=\sin \vert x\vert$ implies that $f$ satisfies the above inequality with $k=1$, but $f$ is not differentiable. But I'm unable in proving the continuity/discontinuity. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want absolute values in the left hand side of the inequality too?

Comment: @mrf No,I'm not talking about Lipschitz functions.

Comment: That implies Lipschitz continuity: $\pm (f(x) - f(y)) \le k |\pm(x-y)|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the inequality to hold for a fixed $k$ and all $x, y$, then:

$$ f(x)-f(y) \le k|x-y| $$
and
$$ f(y)-f(x) \le k|y-x| = k|x-y| $$
so in fact:
$$ |f(x)-f(y)| \le k|x-y| $$
for all $x$, $y$. I.e. you are looking at Lipschitz functions (which are automatically continuous).

Comment: Ah,I'm really foolish.Thanks a lot!